# iOS: Is this a good idea regarding full screen image sizes?

Tags: ios, iphone, image, resolution

I am wondering regarding iOS development if it is a good idea to have 3 image sizes in the following resolution for full screen size. So the sizes should be: iPhone 1x (320x480) iPhone 2x (750x1334) iPhone R4 (640x1136) iPhone 3x (1242x2208)?

Right now, we don't have the resource to make an image for every screen size. Is this an overall good idea?

Edit: This is going to be a login view controller. The background image will look like similar to this http://assets.materialup.com/uploads/4c98fa96-8bc8-406a-8fc7-d451897a1a37/launch-screen.jpg.

Comment: Depends on what is in your image.  It might be better to create a tileable or resizable image so you can use one image for all screen sizes without having to scale it

Comment: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Comment: @dan So theoretically, it might be better to create an image size of 1242x2208 and let iPhone scale it? Because usually downsizing won't lose any quality.

Comment: Theoretically, sure I'm sure there is a situation where that would be acceptable.  Speaking theoretically isn't really useful though.  If you can give more information about your situation you can get better answers

Comment: @Dan. Ok, the background image looks something like this http://assets.materialup.com/uploads/4c98fa96-8bc8-406a-8fc7-d451897a1a37/launch-screen.jpg. This needs to work for iPhone 4,iPhone 5,iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+

Comment: You should have 2 images rendered at @1x, @2x, and @3x for the logo and the skyline thing and everything else should be created from `UIView`s.  It might be better to have the background buildings in a separate image that you could tile across the full width of the screen and place the foreground buildings on top.  Why are you trying to create a whole view controller from one image?

Comment: @Dan, the background will have a custom design. That is something I overlooked. Here is an example on what I mean. http://reddragonwolf14.deviantart.com/art/Gears-Of-War-custom-background-174796813. I was too focus on logos and forgot the background will have a custom design as well.

Comment: In that case I would create the background image in a way that you can tile it and the sides will line up and use one image for all the screen sizes.  You should still render it out at 1x, 2x, and 3x though.

Comment: So the resolutions I listed will be a good idea, right? It should scale to handle the older iPhones if I use scale to fit.

Answer (score 0):

By full view do you mean the Launch File? If so at the bottom of this page [iOS Human Interface Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html) Apple shows these sizes which seem to be the same as yours.

For iPhone 6:

750 x 1334 (@2x) for portrait
1334 x 750 (@2x) for landscape

For iPhone 6 Plus:

1242 x 2208 (@3x) for portrait
2208 x 1242 (@3x) for landscape

Comment: This won't be a launch image. This will be a login view controller.